# Derivatives with dummy indices not commutative after 3d derivative?

Tags: tensors, xact, field-theory

Recently I've encountered the following issue in xAct.

I've defined the Manifold and tensors in the following manner
  [image]

Then consider the following expressions.
  In the case where there are 2 covariant derivatives, the answer is expected. But when I add another covariant derivative the whole simplification process does not work properly.

It should give *zero* but it doesn't. Where is my problem and how can I fix it?

[image]

Here is the full code snippet

```
DefManifold[M4,4,{a,b,c,d,e,f,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t}];
DefMetric[-1, g[-a, -b], CD, {"|", "\[Del]"}, FlatMetric -> True];
DefTensor[\[Epsilon][a, b, c], M4, Symmetric[{a, b, c}]];
DefTensor[\[Omega][a, b, c], M4, Symmetric[{a, b, c}]];
DefTensor[S[a, b, c, d], M4, Symmetric[{a, b, c, d}]];

EXP1 = 4*S[-i, -j, -k, -l] *\[Epsilon][a, b, c]*
CD[-a]@( CD[i]@\[Omega][e, f, -d])
EXP2 = 4*S[i, -j, -k, -l] *\[Epsilon][a, b, c]*
CD[-a]@( CD[-i]@\[Omega][e, f, -d])

EXP1 - EXP2 // SortCovDs // Simplification

EXP3 = 4*S[-i, -j, -k, -l] *\[Epsilon][a, b, c]*
CD[-a]@CD[-b]@( CD[i]@\[Omega][e, f, -d])
EXP4 = 4*S[i, -j, -k, -l] *\[Epsilon][a, b, c]*
CD[-a]@CD[-b]@( CD[-i]@\[Omega][e, f, -d])

EXP3 - EXP4 // Simplification
```